# Как не давать HDD диску остановиться?

Tags: hdd, диск

У меня есть Telegram-бот, который по запросу выдаёт информацию с диска. При этом сама информация считывается за доли секунды, но только если диск уже раскручен.

Если ботом несколько минут не пользоваться, диск остановится и перед считыванием информации должен будет вновь раскрутиться, что занимает около 7 секунд. Соответственно, у бота появляется неприятная задержка.

Как можно это исправить? Желательно без костылей, вроде создания программы-суетолога, которая будет нон-стопом тормошить диск. SSD тоже не вариант. Может есть уже готовое решение?

Comment: В энергонастройках системы убрать отключение дисков при простое